# C issue with dynamically allocating array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

The input file for my program has the first line containing an int (call it N) that will signify how many following integers there will be (each integer on a new line). Then it should read the integers into num_array and print them out. My issue is that num_array is not being allocated properly I think. The debugging statements in the code will print out 8 being the sizeof(num_array) no matter what N is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *num_array;

int main (int argc, char**argv){
    int numThreads = (int) argv[1];
    char *inputFile = argv[2];
    int N = 0;

    char line[20];
    FILE *file = fopen(inputFile, "r");

    int fileCounter = 0;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        if (fileCounter==0){
            N = atoi(line);
            num_array = malloc(sizeof(int)*(N+1));
        }
        else{
            num_array[fileCounter-1] = atoi(line);
        }
        fileCounter++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    int i;

    printf("%d", sizeof(num_array));
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i<sizeof(num_array); i++){
        printf("%d\n", num_array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input file example:

```
9
10
9
3
212
56
99
4
5
6
```

will print out:

```
8  
10
9
3
212
56
99
4
5
```

As you can see, the last element of the array is cut off (does not print 6) and it appears num_array is not being sized properly (should contain N integers with N being the int at the first line of the input file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many problems with your program:

1. The first line of your `main()` function has a very severe mistake

   ```
   int numThreads = (int) argv[1]
   ```

   in c casting does not convert the type, this conversion is certainly possible, but doesn't give the result you expect, you need something like this

   ```
   char *endptr;
   int   numThreads = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
   if (*endptr != '\0')
    {
       printf("`%s' cannot be converted to an integer\n", argv[1]);
       return -1;
    }
   ```
2. You didn't make sure that there was a parameter provided to your program's command line, you need to check that, `argc` contains the number of command line arguments passed to your program + the `argv[0]`, so you must check

   ```
   if (argc < 2)
    {
       printf("Use: %s NumberOfThreads, where NumberOfThreads is `int'\n", argv[0]);
       return -1;
    }
   ```
3. You don't check if `fopen()` returns `NULL`, that would cause more issues when you `fgets()` the `file` pointer.
4. The `sizeof` operator does not give the length of an array it gives the number of bytes occupied by the array, and you variable is not an array, it's a pointer, so the `sizeof` operator in this case is giving the size of a pointer.

   It turns out that your file contains `9` values and in your platform the pointer size is `8`, so `sizeof(num_array)` is `8` which is `9 - 1` hence your are missing one value, you already have the number of elements of the array `N`, so use it.
5. You never call `free()`.

This is a version of your code, it's fixed and it's made safer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *num_array;

int main (int argc, char**argv) 
 {
    char  line[20];
    /*int   numThreads  = 1;*/
    char *inputFile   = "data.dat";
    int   N           = 0;
    int   fileCounter = 0;
    int   i           = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(inputFile, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return -1;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
     {
        if (fileCounter == 0)
         {
            N         = atoi(line);
            num_array = malloc((1 + N) * sizeof(int));
            if (num_array == NULL)
             {
                fclose(file);
                return -1;
             }
         }
        else
         {
            num_array[fileCounter - 1] = atoi(line);
         }
        fileCounter++;
     }
    fclose(file);

    printf("%ld", sizeof(num_array));
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
     {
        printf("%d\n", num_array[i]);
     }
    free(num_array);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: changed it to int numThreads = atoi(argv[1])   and still getting the same result

Comment: @jeremy my answer doesn't say that it will fix your problem, I am stil trying to find the issue, but you should post sample data from your file, and don't use `atoi()` it's not very useful because you can't perform any error checking.

Comment: @jeremy nevermind I just found the sample input file.